# broad leaf commerce war deploy on tomcat

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

On deploying broadleaf commerce war on stanal tomcat I am getting error :-

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'blAdminFilterSecurityInterceptor' while setting bean property 'filterChainMap' with key [/admin*] with key [6]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blAdminFilterSecurityInterceptor' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot create inner bean 'sec:filter-security-metadata-source#18baf36' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sec:filter-security-metadata-source#18baf36': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig] while setting constructor argument with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestKey]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(MergeContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blAdminFilterSecurityInterceptor' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Cannot create inner bean 'sec:filter-security-metadata-source#18baf36' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sec:filter-security-metadata-source#18baf36': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig] while setting constructor argument with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestKey]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sec:filter-security-metadata-source#18baf36': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig] while setting constructor argument with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestKey]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:707)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:654)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredMethods(ReferenceType.java:693)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.addAndRecurse(ResolvedType.java:268)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getMethodsWithoutIterator(ResolvedType.java:261)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.lookupResolvedMember(ResolvedType.java:443)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:200)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:74)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:291)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:106)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:146)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:235)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:101)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:356)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:244)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
```

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

The JVM does not have enough memory indicated by this message in your logs:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

You can give the JVM more memory by using -Xmx. For instance, you can use -Xmx512M for 512MB of memory, -Xmx1024M for 1GB of memory, etc.

We recommend running Broadleaf with at least 512MB of memory per war. So if you are deploying the admin and site war on the same Tomcat instance, you want give the JVM at least 1024MB of RAM. You might also increase the PermSize to 256MB per application via -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.

So to answer your question specifically for Tomcat, create a setenv.sh file in Tomcat's bin directory. Override the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable in that file like so:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS='-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M'
```

That would be for either site OR admin deployed on that Tomcat container. For both applications, you would do this:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS='-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M'
```

Again, this is bare minimum. Your application, depending on the size, might have further memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved TWO issues:
1)**broadleaf with Mysql and tomcat jndi lookup error**
 i.e *ava.sql.SQLException: ${database.driver}*
2) **broadleaf permgerm space error**
i.e *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*

I created a file named setenv.bat in  tomcat's bin directory.

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xmx1024M -Ddatabase.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME -Ddatabase.user=USER -Ddatabase.password=PASSWORD-Ddatabase.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

set "JAVA_OPTS =%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME-DDATABASE_USER=USER -DDATABASE_PASSWORD=PASSWORD-DDATABASE_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

to work it for you 
change the  DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD